# Add paragraph to the right of the loading spinner

Tags: html, css

I am very new to programming, I would be very grateful if you could provide a useful guide to this problem:

I want to align the paragraph to the right of the loading spinner, can anyone help with that?

```css
.loading {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.loading--full-height {
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}
.loading::after {
  content: "";
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #000000;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: loading 0.3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes loading {
  /* Safari support */
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.75);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loading loading--full-height">
<P>Status: <strong>Awaiting for payment...</strong></P>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `.loading::after` with `.loading::before`

```css
.loading {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.loading--full-height {
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}
.loading::before {
  content: "";
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #000000;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: loading 0.3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes loading {
  /* Safari support */
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.75);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loading loading--full-height">
<P>Status: <strong>Awaiting for payment...</strong></P>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish that by changing `.loading::after` to `.loading::before`. This will position the loading pseudo element before the paragraph. Here it is in context:

```css
.loading {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.loading--full-height {
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.loading::before {
  content: "";
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #000000;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: loading 0.3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes loading {
  /* Safari support */
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.75);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loading loading--full-height">
  <P>Status: <strong>Awaiting for payment...</strong></P>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set CSS style

```
.loading::before
```

instead of `.loading::after`

and it's better to add some margin to `<p>`

```
    margin-left: 10px;
```

```css
.loading {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.loading--full-height {
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}
.loading--full-height p {
      margin-left: 10px;
}
.loading::before {
  content: "";
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #000000;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: loading 0.3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes loading {
  /* Safari support */
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.75);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loading loading--full-height">
<P>Status: <strong>Awaiting for payment...</strong></P>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you meant.
I added `flex-direction: row-reverse` to your .loading--full-height class.

```css
.loading {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .loading--full-height {
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
  }
  .loading::after {
    content: "";
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    background: #000000;
    opacity: 0.5;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: loading 0.3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  }
  
  @keyframes loading {
    /* Safari support */
    from {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: scale(1);
    }
    
    to {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: scale(1.75);
    }
  }
```

```html
    <div class="loading loading--full-height">
        <P>Status: <strong>Awaiting for payment...</strong></P>
        </div>
```

Comment: no need to row reverse. it is always better to fix the problem itself and not change the other elements/functions to make the problem invisible